# What is the Idiomatic way to create object in Kotlin if attribute is not empty nor null

Tags: kotlin

what is the idiomatic way to write this code in Kotlin?

```
  fun createAnswerValue(record: Record):  QuestionnaireResponseItemComponent{
    val list = createAnswerList(record)
    if (list.isNotEmpty()) {
        return QuestionnaireResponseItemComponent().apply {
            linkId = record.siblingIndexUID
            answer = list
        }
    }
    return null
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be a one-liner.

UPDATE: As @Tenfour04 mentioned in comments, it would be more performant to check list for non-nullability first:

```kotlin
fun createAnswerValue(): QuestionnaireResponseItemComponent? =
    createAnswerList(record)
        ?.takeIf { it.isNotEmpty() }
        ?.let {
            QuestionnaireResponseItemComponent(
                linkId = record.siblingIndexUID,
                answer = it
            )
        }
```

Comment: I would lift the `takeIf` out of the `let` for readability and to avoid unnecessary object creation.

Comment: @Tenfour04 it's still always creating that Component object before the ``takeIf`` predicate is considered though, right? (Being able to call ``isNotEmpty`` on the list implies ``createAnswerList`` can't return null)

Comment: @cactustictacs that’s why I said it should be lifted out of the let.

Comment: @Tenfour04 yeah that's what I mean - the let will still run and return a value before the following takeIf runs on that value, right? I'm just making sure I'm not missing something since I did a version that avoids it!

Comment: @cactustictacs, this is what I'm suggesting: `createAnswerList(record)?.takeIf { it.isNotEmpty() } ?.let { QuestionnaireResponseItemComponent(linkId = record.siblingIndexUID, answer = it) }`, but with each function on separate lines for readability.

Comment: @Tenfour04 ahhh ok gotcha, I thought you meant tag it on the end of the ``let``, just because of where it was already. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'd do this:

```
fun createAnswerValue(record: Record): QuestionnaireResponseItemComponent? {
    val list = createAnswerList(record)
    return if (list.isNotEmpty()) QuestionnaireResponseItemComponent().apply {
        linkId = record.siblingIndexUID
        answer = list
    } else null
}
```

which is pretty much what you already had, just using `else` and with the `return` lifted out as a result. It's simple and readable!

If you want to use `takeIf` like in @Михаил's answer, I'd probably do it this way:

```
fun createAnswerValue(): QuestionnaireResponseItemComponent? =
    createAnswerList(record)
        .takeIf { it.isNotEmpty }
        ?.let { list ->
            QuestionnaireResponseItemComponent().apply {
                linkId = record.siblingIndexUID
                answer = list
            }
        }
```

the difference being that in this one, the object is only created if it's going to be returned - if you don't care then Михаил's version is obviously more compact!

But this more Kotliny version does the same as the `if/else` one I posted - I'd argue that version is more readable than this (it's not too bad though). Chaining a bunch of calls together can make things nice and readable and elegant, but it can also overcomplicate things and make it hard to understand exactly what's going on. And I've definitely written my fair share of that! So I feel like "idiomatic" code is something to be careful about - knowing your options is good! But go with what works, don't feel like you need to use a language feature because it's there IMO